# Select columns based on column list present in a different table in Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table `T_FUNCTION` in `HR` schema of `Oracle`.

```
FUN_ID FUN_CMD                          
------ ---------------------------------
     1 substr(FIRST_NAME,2,2)           
     2 FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME
```

I need a query which will select `FUN_CMD` column data from `EMPLOYEES` table.

**Example-1:** for `FUN_ID = 1`, I need to get result of following SQL:

```
select substr(FIRST_NAME,2,2) from EMPLOYEES;
```

**Example-2:** for `FUN_ID = 2`, I need to get result of following SQL:

```
select FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME from EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: You can achieve this by introducing a CASE construct into your select along with query nesting.

Comment: if you are looking for a dynamic sql, see this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS00001

Comment: It is not particularly a great idea to store part of your code in tables. There may be some scenarios like when someone  modifies  a row  in the table, or you want to reuse it in another environment where table needs to be created etc.It may  affect several codes dependant on it. Tablespaces are meant to store data and  it would be better to decouple the code from it.

Answer (score 1):

That smells like a *dynamic SQL* or, maybe a better choice, a procedure that returns refcursor. Here's an example:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t_function;

    FUN_ID FUN_CMD
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 substr(ename, 2, 2)
         2 ename ||' '|| job

SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_fun (
  2     par_fun_id   IN     t_function.fun_id%TYPE,
  3     p_out           OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  4  IS
  5     l_cmd   t_function.fun_cmd%TYPE;
  6     l_str   VARCHAR2 (200);
  7  BEGIN
  8     SELECT fun_cmd
  9       INTO l_cmd
 10       FROM t_function
 11      WHERE fun_id = par_fun_id;
 12
 13     l_str := 'select ' || l_cmd || ' from emp';
 14
 15     OPEN p_out FOR l_str;
 16  END;
 17  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> var l_out refcursor
SQL> exec p_fun(1, :l_out);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_out

SU
--
MI
LL
AR
ON
AR
LA
LA
CO
IN
UR
DA
AM
OR
IL

14 rows selected.
```

And another one:

```
SQL> exec p_fun(2, :l_out);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_out

ENAME||''||JOB
--------------------
SMITH CLERK
ALLEN SALESMAN
WARD SALESMAN
JONES MANAGER
MARTIN SALESMAN
BLAKE MANAGER
CLARK MANAGER
SCOTT ANALYST
KING PRESIDENT
TURNER SALESMAN
ADAMS CLERK
JAMES CLERK
FORD ANALYST
MILLER CLERK

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

[CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) expression is going to be useful for your case:

```
select
  (CASE FUN_ID WHEN 1 THEN substr(FIRST_NAME,2,2)
   ELSE FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME END) from EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: I understand your logic. But the options need to come from another table.